# How can I move my cell in objective c for top and right

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am new to ios programming. here, I just wanted to move my cell little bit more right-hand side...and my top view is also covering the screen I wanted to reduce its size to fit correctly with the view..how can I achieve that

Comment: set "section insets" right , left , top , bottom as per your requirement.

Comment: how can I set  that @DixitAkabari

Comment: select " UICollectionview " and got to " show the sizeinspector " and set "section insets" right , left , top , bottom as per your requirement.

Comment: Could you Please show your UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this lines of codes. Its going to fit your cells in collections as you looking for.

```
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            CGFloat spaceBetweenCells = 5;
            CGFloat width = (yourMainView.frame.size.width - spaceBetweenCells) / 2;
            CGFloat height = (yourMainView.frame.size.height - spaceBetweenCells) / 2.5;
            return CGSizeMake(width, width*changeHeight+38 );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
          return UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 0, 0);
    }
```